# Setting the Value of Assembly Attributes programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, assemblyinfo

I want to be able to Set the Assembly 'Description' Attribute

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]  - from AssemblyInfo.cs
```

value of my Program based on some interaction done at runtime.

I know I can read the value by doing:

```
object[] attributes;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false);
string description = ((AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
```

My question is:  Is there a way to set the value programmatically from within my form?

```
assembly.Attribute.Description = newvalue;
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.  Just use a string variable instead of an attribute.

Comment: It would mean that you a) recompile your program (might be ok if you also deliver the source code) or b) make changes to your compiled DLL (e.g. decompile to IL and recompile) which might be possible, but the solution is too complex to simply be answered here on SO.